# Python-dependency, windows (CMake)

Tags: c++, python, installation, cmake

I have a large, crossplatform, python-dependent project, which is built by CMake.
In linux, python is either preinstalled or easily retrived by shell script. But on windows build, i have to install python manually from .msi before running CMake. Is there any good workaround using cmake scripts?

PS All other external dependencies are downloaded from dedicated FTP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't really have to be installed to function properly. For my own CMake based projects on Windows, I just use a .zip file containing the entire python tree. All you need to do is extract it to a temporary directory, add it to your path, and set your PYTHONHOME/PYTHONPATH environment variables. Once that's done, you have a fully operational Python interpreter at your disposal. About the only 'gotcha' on Windows is to make sure you remember to copy the Python DLL out of C:\Windows\system32 into the top-level Python directory prior to creating the .zip.

Comment: TY, i got it. When i took "python.dll" - all went fine. Thx.